# TypeError: import_optional_dependency() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors' for this code

Tags: pandas, pandas-datareader

Here are the code snippet how to pick up 2 higher and lower data points from DataFrame. The computation returned only 2 sets of DataFrame rows where the data points broke above or below the calculated linear regression line in either case.
but:

```py
TypeError: import_optional_dependency() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors' for this code
```

[the actual output is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tDSI.jpg)

#### higher points are returned

```py
while len(df_high)>2:
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x=df_high['Number'], y=df_high['High'])
    df_high = df_high.loc[df_high['High'] > slope * df_high['Number'] + intercept]
    
df_high.tail()
```

#### lower points are returned

```py
while len(df_low)>2:
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x=df_low['Number'], y=df_low['Low'])
    df_low = df_low.loc[df_low['Low'] < slope * df_low['Number'] + intercept]
    
df_low.tail()
```